# PDF for the integral of a Stochastic Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-calculus

My continuous-time, continuous step Stochastic Process P runs from time $t=0$ to $t=t_f$ and generates a path.  I am able to observe its starting and ending position (so $P(0)=a$ and $P(t_f)=b$), but I'm unsure what happened in the middle.  I want to come up with a PDF for the integral of the process from $0$ to $t_f$.

Any advice?

Comment: There isn't enough information to find the pdf.

Comment: There isn't?  Really?

$P$ is known: I have at my disposal a PDF for the location of the process at any time $t$.  I can't think of what more information would be needed.

Comment: I suggest you improve your question to make it explicit what is known. For example, $P$ might be defined in terms of SDE, but the expression for pdf of $P(t)$ might not be available. In order to find pdf of $P(t)$, you need to find the joint pdf for $(P(t), P(t_f))$ and then condition on $P(t_f)=b$.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, if you have a SDE for your process under Ito form, there is under conditions a way to go to the forward and backward equations which gives the time evolution of the probability density. Is it helpful ?